# How to take %,/ and ^ in KeyCombination in javafx keyevent

Tags: javafx, keycode

I have value in combo box that start with <,<=,>,>=,~,/,% and ^ . So what basically i am doing is when user press tab on that combox and inputs any key then generate  combobox result based on first letter of keypressed.
I have successfully managed all digit,letter keys and <,<=,>,>=,~ keys but not able to get %,/ and ^.

Below is code for getting all above special keystrokes on shift combination

```
List<String> combination = Arrays.asList("<","<=",">",">=","~","?");
        for(String keyComb : combination) {
                KeyCharacterCombination keyCombo = new KeyCharacterCombination(keyComb, KeyCombination.SHIFT_DOWN);
                if(keyCombo.match(event)) {
                    System.out.println("in key combination");
                    String key = keyCombo.getCharacter();
                    String pastString = null;
                    ComboBox<String> comboBox = (ComboBox<String>) event
                            .getSource();
                    pastString = comboBox.getValue();
                    ObservableList<String> traversalItems =   comboBox.getItems();
                    comboBox.setValue(getSelectedItem(key, pastString,
                            traversalItems));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about `%` as `SHIFT` + `DIGIT5`.

So (maybe) you should use a `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED` event listener instead of keys combinations.